# why does my div class not work on a nested bold tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a styling class like this, and a bold tag is inside it. the class seems to apply to the regular text and the text area box but not the bold tag. It only works if i put the class in the bold tag itself.

I thought classes should work on everything within the div though? Does it only work on certain tags like textarea/input but not certain other tags like bold? I'm only asking because I'm curious if there is a fundamental rule about html/css I'm missing. I've researched divs and it seems like it should work the way I thought.

```
<style>
.indent
{
    text-indent: -2em; 
    padding-left: 2em;
}
</style>

<div class='indent'>
        <b>Other</b><br>
        blah blah blah.<br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="others"></textarea><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is working fine. please specify where's the problem ?

Comment: @YahyaEssam implement using jsfiddle. Question is clear

Comment: my question wasn't about code not working, I was asking why the indent class doesn't work on the bold tag within it. I wrote that in the question. Is it some kind of rule that a class in a div tag don't apply recursively to nested tags like the bold one?

Comment: it's working on the bold tag https://jsfiddle.net/pc2erzad/

Comment: not working. @YahyaEssam decrease text-indent

Comment: ok so what I was expecting was everything to be indented the same. why is the bold tag one indent short to the left compared to the text and textarea?

Comment: text-indent only affect the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text-indent` will be applied for the first line, that's why only `Other` is getting indented `-2em`. This has nothing to do with the bold tag. For example:

```html
<style>
.indent
{
    text-indent: -2em; 
    padding-left: 2em;
}
</style>

<div class='indent'>
        Other<br>
        <b>blah blah blah.</b><br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="others"></textarea><br><br>
</div>
```

So if you don't want anything to be left indented, you could simply remove it from your class:

```html
<style>
.indent
{
    padding-left: 2em;
}
</style>

<div class='indent'>
        <b>Other</b><br>
        blah blah blah.<br>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="others"></textarea><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: wow I should have bothered understanding the text indent. I just got that class solution from a quick web search. thanks!